# Getting error Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT

Tags: mysql, .net-4.5, quartz-scheduler, quartz, transaction-isolation

I have a local development server where i have tested nearly all quartz functionality (scheduling/execution/e.t.c) where mysql setting log_bin = off 
When i deployed same script on my staging server(log_bin = on)  i am getting following error.

```
JobStoreTX.Log      Failure occurred during job recovery: Couldn't recover jobs: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.
```

Quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't recover jobs: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.

On digging down i am able to found out it is due to binlog_format=Statement

Anyway i can able to work with above setting(mean's cahgning the binlog_format to Mixed)

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestions from mysql forums i have changed the binlog_format = MIXED
And it start working.
What i further suggests is that there should be note in mysql usage for quartz that if log_bin settings is on then binlog_format should be set to MIXED